# is zero vector linearly dependent on other vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If I have 3 column vectors which one of them is a zero vector, is it right to say they are linear dependent ? because (from my understanding) I can multiply out one of the other vector by scalar 0 and obtain the zero vector.Hence, the zero vector is not needed (redundant).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The definition of linear dependence is for non-zero vectors. In this case, you would say “I don’t have three linearly independent vectors”

Comment: Any non-empty (finite) set containing the zero vector is trivially linearly dependent.

Comment: @Mathemagical: The definition of linear dependence doesn't treat zero vectors any differently from nonzero vectors.

Comment: @Mathemagical how come is for non-zero ?

Comment: @StubbornAtom, why does finiteness matter? Isn't an infinite set with the zero vector in it also trivially linearly dependent?

Comment: @GTonyJacobs I put 'finite' within parenthesis precisely for the reason you mention.

Comment: @Mathemagical Who told you that?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I meant to say something the name, not the definition (and thanks, community, for correcting that).  Yes, the definition is met. I think the OP could see that too before asking. Depending on the audience, though, I might choose to say “don’t have linear independence”, though, rather than “have linear dependence”

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's think about the definition of linear independence. It's not about redundancy; it's about whether a non-zero linear combination can equal the zero vector. Now if we have a set $\bf{v},\bf{w},\bf{0}$, there is a non-trivial linear combination that definitely works: $$0{\bf{v}}+0{\bf{w}}+1{\bf{0}}={\bf{0}}$$ That's why the set is linearly dependent.

Comment: @Hurkyl, thank you for that edit. I was just trying to figure out how to fix that issue with bold-face spilling out. Cheers.

Comment: The first result in a Google search is this article http://www.math.uconn.edu/~glaz/math2210f16/Section%20Handouts/sec4_3.pdf, which bizarrely, states a set containing the zero vector is both dependent and independent.

Comment: That is bizarre. It’s like saying 1 is prime...

Answer (score 4):

Yes, and you don't even need the other vectors.

The family $(0)$ itself is linearly dependent. It is a bit of a strange thing to say considering how we use that word in real life, but that's what the definition says !